# How to filter exact many to many

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have User and Room model in Flask SQLAlchemy. I need to filter if Room exists with users [user1, user2, ...]. Filter must be exact.

Here are my models:

```
room_users_table = db.Table(
  'room_users',
    db.metadata,
    db.Column('user', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('room', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('room.id'))
)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    rooms = db.relationship(
        "Room",
        secondary=room_users_table,
        back_populates="users"
    )

class Room(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'room'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    users = db.relationship(
        "User",
        secondary=room_users_table,
        back_populates="rooms"
    )
```

Thanks, I've searched all simular questions and can't find answer.

Comment: By exact do you mean that a `Room` must have only `User`s with the given emails as room users? Not rooms with the given emails and possibly some others.

Comment: Yep, you understand it right. Only rooms with given users. For example if I want send message two User1 and User2, I need to know if room with us 3 already exists. And I need room with us 3 only, not room with us 3 and some other users. I hope, example will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a version of [relational division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29) and some additional filtering:

First build a temporary "table" (a union) of the emails you want to search against:

```
In [46]: emails = ['email1@mail.com', 'email2@mail.com']

In [47]: emails_union = db.union(*(db.select([db.literal(email).label('email')])
                                   for email in emails)).alias()
```

That may look a bit unwelcoming, but it essentially forms an SQL UNION like this:

```
SELECT 'email1@mail.com' AS email
UNION
SELECT 'email2@mail.com' AS email
```

and gives it an alias. Some databases may support other means to generate a new relation from a list, [for example with Postgresql you could](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.alias):

```
In [64]: from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import array

In [65]: emails_relation = db.func.unnest(array(emails)).alias()
```

The division itself is done using a double negation, or 2 nested NOT EXISTS conditions:

```
In [48]: db.session.query(Room).\
    ...:     filter(~db.session.query().select_from(emails_union).
    ...:                filter(~Room.users.any(email=emails_union.c.email)).
    ...:                exists(),
    ...:            ~Room.users.any(User.email.notin_(emails))).\
    ...:     all()
Out[48]: [<__main__.Room at 0x7fad4d238128>]

In [49]: [(r.name, [u.email for u in r.users]) for r in _]
Out[49]: [('room1', ['email1@mail.com', 'email2@mail.com'])]
```

The query pretty much answers the question "find those `Room`s for which no such email exists that is not in `Room.users`" – which finds rooms with all given emails – and then it applies the 3rd NOT EXISTS condition, which filters out rooms with additional emails. Without it the query would also return *room2*, which has emails 1, 2, and 3.

The searches were done against this data:

```
In [10]: users = [User(id=id_, email='email{}@mail.com'.format(id_))
    ...:          for id_ in range(1, 10)]

In [11]: rooms = [Room(id=id_, name='room{}'.format(id_))
    ...:          for id_ in range(1, 10)]

In [18]: db.session.add_all(users)

In [19]: db.session.add_all(rooms)

In [20]: for room, user1, user2 in zip(rooms, users, users[1:]):
    ...:     room.users.append(user1)
    ...:     room.users.append(user2)
    ...:     

In [21]: rooms[1].users.append(users[0])

In [22]: db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score -1):

After two days of research I have a temporary solution.

```sql
-- room_users is the "secondary" table in 
   -- sqlalchemy many to many between User and Room
select room.name, room_users.room 
    from room_users join room on room_users.room = room.id 
    where room_users.user in (1,2) 
    group by room_users.room having count(*) = 2;
```

In python it will be something like this:

```
# members contains user emails
members = ['email1@mail.com', 'email2@mail.com']
db.session.query(Room.name).join(Room.users).filter(
    User.email.in_(members)
).group_by(Room.id).having(
    func.count(Room.id) == len(members)
).first()
```

Comment: The query will end up returning rooms with inexact matches as well, because the JOIN will only produce rows that match the IN condition – filtering out possible extra users – and so all Rooms that have users with the given emails will produce `len(members)` rows in the group. For example if you have a room  with Users email1, 2 and 3, this query will return it.

Comment: You are right, it's not working. But not in your example, because count will be 2. But when I will filter for three users, and find Room with 2 of this users as members and last member will be another user, this Room will be in results, because count will be 3. I don't understand why this is so complicated. I need to rethink application architecture. Thanks @IljaEverilä

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "count will be 3". It will be 2 for all rooms that have users with emails *email1@mail.com* and *email2@mail.com*, because after the JOIN and WHERE clause filtering those rows are left per room group.

Comment: Ooh, really, now I understand it.