# How to filter many to many that has all item in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

```
class Group(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)

    user = db.relationship("User", backref="group", cascade="delete")


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Group.id, ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)


group_names = ["foo", "bar"]
User.query.filter(User.group.any(Group.name.in_(group_names))).all()
```

This query can filter `User` that are at least in `foo` or `bar` group. However, I want to query the users that are in **BOTH** groups.

Is there a way to do in SQLAlchemy **WITHOUT** using a for-loop to create a chain of or queries?

Comment: Just to be sure, do you want to find users that are exactly in those groups and in those groups only, or users that have those groups and possibly others? Sounds like you might be interested in relational division with reminder, or just an intersect. Here are 2 related Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438529/sqlalchemy-array-agg-and-matching-an-input-list, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673699/how-to-filter-exact-many-to-many