# sqlalchemy, select objects that has all tags

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have sqlalchemy models:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, and_
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()

class TopicToPizzaAssociation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    pizza_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('pizza.id'), primary_key=True)
    topic_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('topic.id'), primary_key=True)
    topic = relationship("Topic")
    pizza = relationship("Pizza")

class Pizza(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pizza'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    topics = relationship("TopicToPizzaAssociation")

    def add_topics(self, topics):
        used_topics = {t.topic.product for t in self.topics}
        associations = []
        for topic in topics:
            if topic.product not in used_topics:
                associations.append(TopicToPizzaAssociation(pizza=self, topic=topic))
                used_topics.add(topic.product)
        p1.topics.extend(associations)

class Topic(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'topic'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    product = Column(String(), nullable=False)
```

I need to select all pizza objects which have the required set of topics:

```
t1 = Topic(product='t1')
t2 = Topic(product='t2')
t3 = Topic(product='t3')

session = Session()
session.add_all([t1, t2, t3])

p1 = Pizza()
p2 = Pizza()

p1.add_topics([t1, t2, t1])
p2.add_topics([t2, t3])

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session.add_all([p1, p2])
session.commit()

values = ['t1', 't2']
topics = session.query(Topic.id).filter(Topic.product.in_(values))
pizza = session.query(Pizza).filter(Pizza.topics.any(TopicToPizzaAssociation.topic_id.in_(
    topics
))).all()
```

This returns all pizza that have one of topics. If I try to replace `any` with `all`, it doesn't work.

I've found that it is possible to make a query with JOIN and COUNT, but I couldn't build sqlalchemy query. Any possible solution will suit me.

Comment: Are you open to changes in the structure of your models, or is the structure set and cannot be changed?

Comment: I can change the structure.

Comment: By "required set" do you mean that you wan't pizzas with given toppings only, or with given toppings and possibly some others as well.

Comment: I want pizza with given toppings and possibly some others.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438529/sqlalchemy-array-agg-and-matching-an-input-list, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673699/how-to-filter-exact-many-to-many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there is a stack of reading you can do about SQLAlchemy relationships [in the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html).

Your code closely matches the [`Association Object`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) pattern which is (from the docs):

> ...used when your association table contains additional columns beyond those which are foreign keys to the left and right tables

I.e., if there was something specific about the individual relationship between a `Pizza` and `Topic`, you would store that information in line with the relationship between foreign keys in the association table. Here's the example that the docs give:

```
class Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    left_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('left.id'), primary_key=True)
    right_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra_data = Column(String(50))
    child = relationship("Child", back_populates="parents")
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Association", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parents = relationship("Association", back_populates="child")
```

Note the column `extra_data` defined on the `Association` object.

In your example, there is no such need for an extra_data type field in `Association` so you can simplify expressing the relationship between `Pizza` and `Topic` by using the [Many to Many Pattern outlined in the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many).

The main benefit that we can get from that pattern is that we can directly relate the `Pizza` class to the `Topic` class. The new models look something like this:

```
class TopicToPizzaAssociation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    pizza_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('pizza.id'), primary_key=True)
    topic_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('topic.id'), primary_key=True)


class Pizza(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pizza'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    topics = relationship("Topic", secondary='association')  # relationship is directly to Topic, not to the association table

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'pizza {self.id}'


class Topic(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'topic'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    product = Column(String(), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.product
```

The differences to your original code are:

- No relationships defined on the `TopicToPizzaAssociation` model. With this pattern we can directly relate `Pizza` to `Topic` without having relationships on the association model.
- Added `__repr__()` methods to both models so they print nicer.
- Removed the `add_topics` method from `Pizza` (will explain that more later).
- Added the `secondary='association'` argument to `Pizza.topics` relationship. This tells sqlalchemy that the foreign key path needed for the relationship to `Topic` is through the `association` table.

Here is the testing code and I've put some comments in there:

```
t1 = Topic(product='t1')
t2 = Topic(product='t2')
t3 = Topic(product='t3')

session = Session()
session.add_all([t1, t2, t3])

p1 = Pizza()
p2 = Pizza()

p1.topics = [t1, t2]  # not adding to the pizzas through a add_topics method
p2.topics = [t2, t3]

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session.add_all([p1, p2])
session.commit()

values = [t2, t1]  # these aren't strings, but are the actual objects instantiated above

# using Pizza.topics.contains
print(session.query(Pizza).filter(*[Pizza.topics.contains(t) for t in values]).all())  # [pizza 1]

values = [t2, t3]
print(session.query(Pizza).filter(*[Pizza.topics.contains(t) for t in values]).all())  # [pizza 2]

values = [t2]
print(session.query(Pizza).filter(*[Pizza.topics.contains(t) for t in values]).all())  # [pizza 2, pizza 1]
```

So this only returns pizzas that have all of the prescribed topics, but not *only* the prescribed topics.

The reason I left out your `add_topics` method is that you used that method to check for duplicate `Topics` added to a given `Pizza`. That's fine, but the primary key of the association table won't let you add a duplicate topic for a pizza anyway, so I think it's better to let the database layer manage that and just handle the exception that occurs in application code.

Answer (score 0):

A query to fetch all `Pizza` with given `Topic`s (and possibly more) can be expressed using a slightly hard to read double negation:

```
session.query(Pizza).\
    filter(~session.query(Topic).
           filter(Topic.product.in_(values),
                  ~session.query(TopicToPizzaAssociation).
                  filter(TopicToPizzaAssociation.topic_id == Topic.id,
                         TopicToPizzaAssociation.pizza_id == Pizza.id).
                  correlate(Pizza, Topic).
                  exists()).
           exists())
```

In English it reads along the lines of "Fetch pizza where not exists a given topic [sic] that is not in this pizza."

> This returns all pizza that have one of topics. If I try to replace `any` with `all`, it doesn't work.

SQL does not have [universal quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification) and so there is no `all()` operator for relationships the way that [`any()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any) maps to `EXISTS`. But

```
FORALL x ( p ( x ) )
```

is logically equivalent to

```
NOT EXISTS x ( NOT p ( x ) )
```

which the above query takes advantage of. It is also described as how to perform [relational division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_(%C3%B7)) in SQL:

- https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/
- https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/relational-division/
- http://www.inf.usi.ch/faculty/soule/teaching/2016-fall/db/division.pdf