# SQLAlchemy filter on list attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following model defined with Flask-SQLAlchemy:

```py
"""models.py"""

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

skill_candidate = db.Table(
    'SkillCandidate',
    db.Column('skill_id', db.String, db.ForeignKey('skill.id')),
    db.Column('candidate_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('candidate.id')))

class Candidate(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    skills = db.relationship("Skill", secondary=skill_candidate)

class Skill(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
```

What am trying to achieve is the following :
I want to return all the candidates who possess skills provided in a list input (even ideally, a list of skill_id)

I tried the following :

```py
def get_skilled_candidates(skill_ids):
    return Candidate.query.join(skill_candidate).\
       filter(and_(*[skill_candidate.c.skill_id == skill_id for skill_id in skill_ids])).\
            all()
```

The aim was to filter all candidates for every skill and compose it with a and_ statement

It works well if I use a list of 1 item (it returns all candidates that possess the skill) but does not if I add more skills in the input list (even tho I have candidates in base that fit the criteria)

Comment: Could you show as what exactly is `constraint_item_candidate` and `constraint_item_candidate.c` in your query?

Comment: my mistake, it's a typo. ```constraint_item_candidate``` is actually meant to be ```skill_candidate```, the association table of Skill and Candidate.
skill_candidate.c is the way of accessing column fields for a ```db.Table ``` instance

Comment: You need relational division / "for all", which translates to "not exists skill id that not exists in skill_candidate". Some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438529/sqlalchemy-array-agg-and-matching-an-input-list, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673699/how-to-filter-exact-many-to-many

Comment: Awesome pinpoint, but I cannot totally wrap my head around that double negation... I'll try to write an expression as soon as I handle it

Comment: I thought I had it, I tried first sending the raw query:
```SQL
select * from SkillCandidate where not (exists (select * from SkillCandidate where SkillCandidate.skill_id not in (1, 2)))
```
But it results in returning an empty result  (1 and 2 are the ids of the required skills)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments, what you'd need is a `FORALL` operation ([universal quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification)), or [relational division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_(%C3%B7)).

```
FORALL x ( p(x) )
```

can be expressed as

```
NOT ( EXISTS x ( NOT ( p(x) ) ) )
```

which is a bit unwieldy and hard to reason about, if you don't know about `FORALL` and their relationship. Given your models it could look like:

```
def get_skilled_candidates(skill_ids):
    # Form a temporary derived table using unions
    skills = db.union_all(*[
        db.select([db.literal(sid).label('skill_id')])
        for sid in skill_ids]).alias()

    return Candidate.query.\
        filter(
            ~db.exists().select_from(skills).where(
                ~db.exists().
                    where(db.and_(skill_candidate.c.skill_id == skills.c.skill_id,
                                  skill_candidate.c.candidate_id == Candidate.id)).
                    correlate_except(skill_candidate))).\
        all()
```

There are of course other ways to express the same query, such as:

```
def get_skilled_candidates(skill_ids):
    return Candidate.query.\
        join(skill_candidate).\
        filter(skill_candidate.c.skill_id.in_(skill_ids)).\
        group_by(Candidate.id).\
        having(db.func.count(skill_candidate.c.skill_id.distinct()) ==
               len(set(skill_ids))).\
        all()
```

which essentially checks by count that all skill ids were matched.

If using Postgresql you could also do:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import array_agg

def get_skilled_candidates(skill_ids):
    # The double filtering may seem redundant, but the WHERE ... IN allows
    # the query to use indexes, while the HAVING ... @> does the final filtering.
    return Candidate.query.\
        join(skill_candidate).\
        filter(skill_candidate.c.skill_id.in_(skill_ids)).\
        group_by(Candidate.id).\
        having(array_agg(skill_candidate.c.skill_id).contains(skill_ids)).\
        all()
```

This is somewhat equivalent with the partly Python solution from the other answer.

Also, the aggregate `EVERY` could be used:

```
def get_skilled_candidates(skill_ids):
    # Form a temporary derived table using unions
    skills = db.union_all(*[
        db.select([db.literal(sid).label('skill_id')])
        for sid in skill_ids]).alias()

    # Perform a CROSS JOIN between candidate and skills
    return Candidate.query.\
        join(skills, db.true()).\
        group_by(Candidate.id).\
        having(db.func.every(
            db.exists().
                where(db.and_(skill_candidate.c.skill_id == skills.c.skill_id,
                              skill_candidate.c.candidate_id == Candidate.id)).
                correlate_except(skill_candidate))).\
        all()
```

Comment: Excellent. That's what I was missing: the initial condition  ~db.exists().select_from(skills)
 I was also considering the count condition part. 
I am gonna try to test all those solutions performance-wise

Answer (score 10):

You could query all candidates with any of the skills in your list and then filter the result with a list comprehension. This may not be as performant as the relational division approach mentioned by [@IljaEverilä](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%C3%A4), but it certainly simplifies the query aspect.

```
skill_ids = ['id_1', 'id_2']
candidates = session.query(Candidate).\
    filter(Candidate.skills.any(Skill.id.in_(skill_ids)).\
    all()

candidates = [
    c for c in candidates
    if set(s.id for s in c.skills).issuperset(skill_ids)
]
```

Comment: I could go for this, but I am concerned about the performance impact of letting python handling the filtering instead of the sql engine

Comment: @AugBar - yeah, just realized that I think I missed an important part of your question where you are wanting to get a list of only those candidates that possess _all_ of the skills in the list, correct?

Comment: They have to possess at least all the skills specified in the list

Comment: @AugBar - edited to produce the desired results, but I would guess that the relational division approach mentioned in the question comments would be more performant.